# Habilitar botón después de comprobar que los inputs no estén vacíos

Tags: jquery

Necesito habilitar un botón después de validar que los inputs no estén vacíos, pero al ingresar datos en el primer input el botón ya se habilita.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#envia').prop("disabled", true);
  $("input[type='text']").each(function(index){
   $("input[type='text']").change(function(){
    if($(this).val().length > 0){
      $('#envia').prop("disabled", false);
     }
    }); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="uno"><br>
<input type="text" name="dos"><br>
<input type="text" name="tres"><br>
<input type="button" id="envia" value="Guardar">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#envia').prop("disabled", true);
  $("input[type='text']").each(function(index){
    $("input[type='text']").change(function(){
        checkInputs();
    }); 
  });

});

function checkInputs() {
    var disabled = false;
  $("input[type='text']").each(function(index){
    if($(this).val().length == 0){
        disabled = true;
    }
  });
  $('#envia').prop("disabled", disabled);
}
```

Te dejo una solución al problema

Comment: La respuesta es correcta, pero las respuestas de solo código sin explicación se consideran de baja calidad, por favor agrega mas información para mejorar la calidad.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias!